# Menu bars and docks

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While I imagine some might find it useful for users to know the technical name of the pieces of their operating system, most will only know [wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wingpanel) as the [menu-bar](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menu-bar), [plank](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plank) as the [dock](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dock), and [slingshot](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slingshot) as the [applications-menu](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications-menu). I recommend using the common name as their primary names, with the technical names as aliases and mentions in the tag usage recommendations. The duplicate [pantheon-dock](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-dock) should also redirect to the existing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these tags simply aren't in use, and typically we encourage the use of tags being the exposed name in the OS. For wingpanel and slingshot that differs a little, but `file-manager` goes to `pantheon-files` and `lockscreen` to `greeter`. I have added the wingpanel and slingshot redirects in a similar style.

Comment: I was hoping to have a discussion on why we use `wingpanel` instead of `menu bar`, etc., unless I'm missing a prior discussion? Devs and tinkerers might know it better as the former, but I imagine that would confuse the OS's target demographic looking for online help (and thus possibly be against the OS's philosophy of not making new users learn the inner workings/file systems/etc.)

Comment: As I said, most of them should match the names that are exposed (usually in an about section). This is a little trickier for things like slingshot and greeter which are integrated parts of the OS, but historically that's how things have been done, likely because of this page: https://elementary.io/support which sends "Music" to "Noise"

Comment: But that page also sends "Mail" to [tag:geary]—it can change. Anyway, it seems that you disagree, but as a new user I was confused by the above tags and I imagine all less technical users will be as well. There's no reason a non-technical, common support user should know that the Music app is "Noise", and I imagine that's how it was intentionally designed (hence the app is called "Music" in Slingshot and the dock. Not sure why Stack Exchange should be the place for them to stumble into it.

Comment: I assume it would be because without technical terminology, it is very hard to figure out what people want. People tagging "Music" will simply see "Noise" as a result. Tag descriptions should clear that up. I'll put it to UX.

Comment: For instance, if you type "top-bar", it suggest wingpanel, "The bar that appears at the top of the screen."

Comment: I get the original point of using the technical name for specificity, but I'd be curious what the UX team thinks both for SEO and the OS's target demo about calling the Music app "Music" in the Applications menu, dock, and website, but "Noise" on Stack Exchange and Launchpad, and so on for the other apps and UI elements mentioned above (e.g., putting `wingpanel` as an alias of [`menu-bar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_bar) rather than vice versa)

Comment: Everyone in the question will call it Music, just the tag will auto-correct to Noise. For SEO, that should be fine, better, probably.

Comment: but wingpanel *isn't* a menubar